# ¿Cómo puedo abrir Google Drive al pulsar un botón (Android)?

Tags: android

Lo que necesito es abrir Google Drive al pulsar un botón en Android. Tengo este códigopero lo único que hace es preguntar con qué cuenta quiero iniciar sesión en Drive y no lo abre.

```
GoogleApiClient apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .build();
```

Gracias.

Comment: creo que lo que necesitas es [Enviar a un usuario a otra app](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html), Lo que tienes que hacer es indicarle a un intent que abra google drive. Te pondria codigo pero no lo he hecho jeje, pero puede que la documentacion que puse te guie

Comment: @PacoPepe imagino que el botón ya lo tienes solo agrega un listener  a tu botón

Answer (score 0):

La manera más sencilla de invocar a otra aplicación es utilizando el **`PackageManager`** de android. Y como no a través de un `Intent`.

Para realizar esta tarea debemos de saber el nombre del **`paquete`** de la aplicación en cuestión. Y el nombre del paquete de google drive es **`"com.google.android.apps.docs"`**.

Ejemplo sencillo.

**1)** *Creamos layout con el botón que es lo que estás pidiendo.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Drive"
        android:onClick="irADrive"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**2)** *Y ahora en el MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void irADrive(View view) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
        if (intent != null)
            startActivity(intent);
        else
            Log.e("LanzarDrive", "La aplicación no está disponible en tu dispositivo");
    }
}
```

---

Ahora solo nos queda por verificar el funcionamiento del mismo *'Debemos tener la aplicación instalada :)'*. Yo lo hice y funcionando.
Saludos!!

Answer (score -1):

Para esto usa el método [getLaunchIntentForPackage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)),

> [getLaunchIntentForPackage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)) : Devuelve un intent para iniciar una
>   actividad de puerta de entrada en un paquete. Esto se usa, por
>   ejemplo, para implementar un botón "abrir" cuando se navega por
>   paquetes.

Para usarlo es importante tener el `package name` de la aplicación que deseas abrir, y que es el identificador único de cada aplicación, en el caso de `Google Drive` el package name es "`com.google.android.apps.docs`", para abrir la aplicación `Google Drive` lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
String packageName = "com.google.android.apps.docs";
Intent i = new Intent();
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

De esta forma puedes abrir la aplicación `Google Drive`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si deseas llamar lo anterior desde un botón, puedes crear uno o tomar la referencia de tu botón en el layout por ejemplo:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

y a este botón asignarle un listener [OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)  para que al ser pulsado, esta abra la aplicación:

```
    //Obtiene referencia de boton en layout.
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    //Agrega listener
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Llama código para abrir Google Drive
            String packageName = "com.google.android.apps.docs";
            Intent i = new Intent();
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.